# Submitting disabled fields on content entry forms?

Tags: 7, entities, taxonomy-terms

I need to submit content entry forms that have default values set in disabled elements.  However, if I remember correctly, HTTP specifies that fields that are disabled do not have their values sent to the web server (or are dropped by the web server, I can't remember).

Specifically, I have a tag field (term reference) that is a select list, and it defaults to a particular value that is updated twice a year and it cannot be changed by users submitting the form.  I want this field to appear to the user, but at the same time I want it disabled so they can't change it.

How can I submit a disabled field in Drupal 7?

Comment: Yeah it's part of the specification that people need to be able to observe these fields so that they know what report they are creating.

Comment: Oops sorry I realised that just after I posted that comment and deleted it :)

Comment: I'm just too quick on the feedback :)

Comment: I pretty much know what needs to happen.  In the flow of HTML there needs to be a hidden field that appears right before the disabled field, with the value in the hidden field equal to the disabled field, and also the name attribute of the hidden field needs to be equal to the disabled field.  I just tested this via Chrome Inspector and the form submission worked.  I just don't know how to inject this effect into Drupal.

Comment: Does that not potentially break the security of the form? It would be fairly easy to manipulate that hidden field before submission so a malevolent user could inject values into the form you're not expecting

Comment: I had the same thought but security isn't a huge concern in this case.  It's a reporting form that will be used by approximately 70 users (mostly professors and faculty).  Obviously though I'd prefer it to be a 100% secure form, free from malevolent user abuse, but it's not a huge priority in this case.  You get +1 for the use of the word 'malevolent' by the way.

Comment: Came across this post on stack exchange. It is similar to what you mentioned in one of your previous comments. But the worst part is where do you place the hidden field .. before or after the disabled element as it plays a crucial role as well as per comments in the post. :p

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191113/disable-select-form-field-but-still-send-the-value

Comment: Yeah this is pretty much what I'm doing.  My `hook_form_alter` is going to just pull the existing values from the select field, duplicate the name attribute and value, and then I'm using #weight to drop it all the way at the end, because the HTTP specification states that with multiple elements with identical names, the last instance of an element with the same name, that value is used, which is why I asked the other question that I did about getting the hidden element to appear last.

Answer (score 1):

As long as security is not a concern, the following can be done:

1. Use `hook_form_alter` to create an additional hidden field in the form.
2. The name attribute of this hidden field should be equivalent to the name of the disabled field.  The value attribute of the hidden field should be equivalent to the currently selected value.
3. The hidden field needs to be placed at the very END of the HTML form, or at the very lease, immediately after the disabled field.  The reason for this is that, according to the HTTP specification, if you submit multiple fields with the same name, the last field in the flow of the HTML has it's value submitted above all other submissions.  Of course, disabled fields have their values dropped altogether, so the hidden field could technically appear anywhere in the form, but this would be "best practice".

Here's some code from my `hook_form_alter`:

```
function ccom_validations_form_challenges_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['my_field'] = array (
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value' => 'schweet'
  );
  $defaultValue = $form['field_reporting_period']['und']['#default_value'][0];
  $form['my_field']['#attributes']['name'] = 'field_reporting_period[und]';
  $form['my_field']['#attributes']['value'] = $defaultValue;
  $form['my_field']['#weight'] = '4';
  $form['field_reporting_period']['#disabled'] = 'true';
  dpm($form);
}
```

So in the above code you can see how I've assigned the name and value to the field, adjusted the weight so it appears last in the list (using DPM I found that the the highest weight value was 3 in the form, so I used 4 so it was weighted the heaviest), and finally indicated that the original field I wanted disabled is in fact disabled.  Note that you disable form fields in Drupal using the meta attribute `#disabled`, rather than specifying the disabled attribute directly in the `#attributes` array.  Weird.

Now this obviously isn't secure, because anybody with any browser HTML manipulation tool like the Chrome Inspector can enable the field and move it to last in the list and then it's value would be used rather than the hidden fields.  I'll revisit this later if security really becomes a concern in this area.